Likehood ratio test vs wald test multicolinearity
I want to do a project about the display how robust likehood ratio testing can be. My idea is to show that in a logistic regression where one predictor displays multicolinearity the wald test show less reliable results in the p value in LRT, because the LRT takes a look at the whole model rather than individual coefficients. I just don’t know how to justify this properly and how valid this idea is. Can someone provide some orientation?
My scenario is for example a logistic regression with five predictors and two of those show high correlation. I run the model and run the Wald test to check if all the coefficients are significant in the model. However the results might be compromised due to the correlation. My idea was to then run LRT with the full model and another without the variables that are compromised and test if LRT tells me the full model is better. The idea is to show that LRT is more robust than Wald test because LRT looks over all the model rather than individual coefficients.

Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean that one predictor shows multicollinearity? Multicollinearity necessarily involves more than one feature. Also, what kind of test do you intend to run, what null and alternative hypotheses for both the Wald and likelihood ratio tests? In particular, are those null and alternative hypotheses the same for each test?

My scenario is for example a logistic regression with five predictors and two of those show high correlation, I run the model and run the wald test to check if all the coefficients are significant in the model . However the results might be compromised due to the correlation. My idea was to then run lrt with the full model and another without the variables that are compromised and test if lrt tells me the full model is better. The idea is show lrt is more robust than wald test because overlooks all the model rather than individual coeficients. Is my idea valid?

I took the liberty to include most of your comment into the original question. On this site, comments are easy to overlook and can even be deleted. Including such details in the original question makes it easier for others visiting this site to see what's going on.

I think that you are using too restricted a view of what Wald tests can accomplish with multiple coefficients.
You are correct that, with two correlated predictors, Wald tests on estimates of their individual coefficients will tend to have high p-values due to the correlation. You can, however, do a Wald "chunk test" on both of their coefficients together. That would be most equivalent to what you seem to suggest: performing a likelihood-ratio test (LRT) between two models, one with both the predictors and one without either of them.
This answer shows how correlation can lead to an offsetting covariance between the individual coefficient estimates and thus a significant "chunk test" result. Although that answer is in the context of linear least squares regression, the principle extends to any regression with a multivariate normal variance-covariance matrix.
The wald.test() function of the R aod package is one implementation allowing for chunk tests. Frank Harrell's rms package uses such tests routinely to evaluate multiple coefficients involved in interactions or splines.
If you want to compare Wald and likelihood-ratio tests, be careful to compare like to like. If you evaluate only individual coefficients with a Wald test, just evaluate single coefficients with the corresponding LRT. If you evaluate multiple coefficients together with an LRT, perform the corresponding Wald "chunk test."
With those precautions this still could be a useful exercise. The usual advantage of likelihood-ratio tests over Wald tests is that Wald tests are based on having a multivariate normal distribution of coefficient estimates, necessarily symmetrical around the point estimate. That holds asymptotically in the limit of large numbers of cases, but might not hold with small data sets. Likelihood-ratio tests don't require that symmetry, so they can be more reliable with low numbers of cases. See this page for discussion about the three types of tests on models fit via maximum likelihood. Comparing Wald and likelihood-ratio tests as a function of sample size thus could be instructive.

thank you! I will look Into wald "chunk test" with more detail.
